# How to concatenate word count and string in autohotkey

Tags: codingkey

How to concatenate word count and string in autohotkey

```
global p = "ppp"
global level = 4
global g = "ggg"
MsgBox %p%%level*5%%g%
```

How to output `ppp20ggg`

Answer (score -1):

you can try it

```
MsgBox % p . (level * 5) . g
```